# How to select data without headers in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy desired columns from one excel spreadsheet to another. I want to copy the data without the two first columns of headers. My desired header names are saved in a hidden sheet with all reference values called **Ref**. So I search all the headers and copy the whole column to another sheet and then delete the first two rows separately. Is there a way an alternative to this?
The code I am using is as below for your reference.

```
Dim nCtr As Integer: nCtr = 3
 If FileExists(FilePath) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No File Exists in the location. Please update and try again."
    LookupData_Copy = False
Else
    Set SrcWbook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath, True, True)
    Set SrcWsheet = SrcWbook.Sheets(targetSheet)
    Set ValueSheet = SrcWbook.Sheets("Ref")
    For Each jCTR In ValueSheet.Range("K3:K5").Cells 'Change range
     Set tCTR = SrcWsheet.Range("A3:X50").Find(What:=jCTR.Value, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                 MatchCase:=False)
     If Not tCTR Is Nothing Then
        SrcWsheet.Columns(tCTR.Column).Copy _
          Destination:=CurrentWorkbook.Sheets(targetSheet).Cells(1, nCtr)
        nCtr = nCtr + 1
        'MsgBox tCTR
    Else:    MsgBox "Title Not Found"
   End If
Next jCTR
SrcWbook.Close False


Sheets(targetSheet).Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Sheets(targetSheet).Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
```

ETA - Another reason I ask this is because I want to use this piece of code to append more data to the next row. The code gets really complex when I have to delete the headers from the middle

Comment: What is the problem with the way you are doing it?

Comment: I want to use this piece of code to append more data to the next row. The code gets really complex when I have to delete the headers from the middle

Comment: I've edited my post with the comments

Comment: copy the range and not the column then.  tCTR is a range object so use offset to eliminate the two rows with headers.  The use Worksheet.UsedRange to get the last cell of the data and copy that over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following (NOT tested) might work to only copy the relevant data to the new destination.

I assume your headers are in Rows 1 and 2.  If not, change the `3` to whatever the first row of data is.

```
If Not tCTR Is Nothing Then
    With SrcWsheet
        .Range(.Cells(3, tCTR.Column), .Cells(.Rows.Count, tCTR.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
          Destination:=CurrentWorkbook.Sheets(targetSheet).Cells(1, nCtr)
        nCtr = nCtr + 1
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:
LR is used to define the last row of the table in SrcWsheet and then you copy data from 3 row till the last one (LR)

```
Dim LR as Long 
LR = SrcWsheet.Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
SrcWsheet.Range(Cells(3,tCTR.Column),Cells(LR,tCTR.Column).Copy 
CurrentWorkbook.Sheets(targetSheet).Cells(1, nCtr)
```